# Hibernate, Java & Ehcache stale data

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I am a relatively amateur user of hibernate and ehcache.
I'm faced with an issue, on a pre-existing application (using Hibernate v5.1.4.Final and Ehcache v2.6.11), of a dataset being cached indefinitely until caching is either disabled, or the app has been restarted.

I've configured my ehcache.xml to read like:

```
<defaultCache
    maxElementsInMemory="10000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300"
    timeToLiveSeconds="300"
    overflowToDisk="true"
/>
<cache
    name="org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache"
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="5000"
    overflowToDisk="true"
    timeToLiveSeconds="300"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300"
    eternal="false"
/>
<cache
    name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="500"
    overflowToDisk="true"
    eternal="false"
    timeToLiveSeconds="300"
/>
<cache
    name="dbItem"
    maxElementsInMemory="1000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="30"
    timeToLiveSeconds="30"
    overflowToDisk="true"
/>

</ehcache>
```

I've decorated the class for the db model like:

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region = "dbItem")
public class DbItem { .. }
```

and then queried the database like

```
List<DbItem> result = entityManager.createQuery(criteria).setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true).getResultList();
```

When I update the database manually, I still see the incorrect results after 300 seconds.
Specifically, what I'm seeing is a list of 'names' which is a field on the database record 'dbItem.Name' never changing.

On first load (after app restart) I might see 'Peter 1' on the list of items through the view of the app. If I update this directly in the database to 'Peter 2' then wait more than 300 seconds, then refresh the page on the browser, I'm still seeing 'Peter 1'.
This remains as such until I restart the app where I assume the cache is force dumped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share a minimal reproducible example of your problem (for example on github).